# On the Chat 'Catch-Up' Page, Show Messages from Rooms that I've Favorited

Tags: feature-request, chat

Right now if you go to the catch-up page, you'll see that it gives you messages from rooms you've been active in.

Because that list could get really large really fast, it would be much more in my interest if you would only display new messages form rooms I've starred. This would let me control which rooms I got updates for, instead of just every room I happened to walk into.

Comment: As an aside; currently it lists those *first*.